# How to send data windows form application to website

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am creating an **windows application** in c#.
in this application i am creating an feed back form for client feedback.
now i want to submit all data this feedback form to my on site.

The the puzzle is that **my website is in PHP** .

should i go with this combination?

i min **c# app and PHP website** and sent data via url and grab it on site using GET method, or i need to create a separate website in asp for this action and if you say YES the please tell me .

how to do this action in ASP

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8538892/1447657 - had you have a look at this? then use `$_GET` or `$_POST` in PHP to get the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the answer . This question may already have an answer here

[pass string from C# Windows Form Application to php webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801877/pass-string-from-c-sharp-windows-form-application-to-php-webpage)

Answer (score 1):

You can simple send a Get/Post-Request to your PHP-Page:
[Generate HTTP Requests using c#](http://codesamplez.com/programming/http-request-c-sharp)

and then Read the data via: $Get or $Post.

You can do the same with ASP.Net, via QueryString:

```
string cParam = Request.QueryString["param"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Website language doesn't really matter as long as you code to get the proper form values. You can use a GET or a POST as well based on type and quantity of data sent across.

You can HTTPRequest and HTTPResponse classes to send response to the Website.

Answer (score 0):

Use Same Data base, and place data from window application and get it from web application

Comment: thanks main . i am such a stupid . from last 30 min i thinking about everything . how i forget this little thing .